# Understanding Recursion with Merge sort

Tags: recursion, mergesort

I see some of the posts to understand merge sort. I know recursive methods maintains stack to hold values. **(my understand was return statement result will be in stack )**

```
private int recur(int count) {
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.println(count);
        return count + recur(--count); // this value will be in stack.
    }
    return count;
}
```

I am confusing in merge sort how stack is maintaining here.

```
private void divide(int low, int high) { 
    System.out.println("Divide => Low: "+ low +" High: "+ high);
    if (low < high) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2; 
        divide(low, middle); // {0,7},{0,3}, {0,1} ;
        divide(middle + 1, high); // {0,0};  high = 1; // 2nd divide
        combine(low, middle, high);
    }
}
```

1. Is stack for all local variables?
2. When 2nd recursive method calls, 1st recursive will also join? 
   How stack are maintained in such cases?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkdwpdHLuII) explains it best.

Comment: You will understand recursion a lot easier with simpler problems. Even before that you should look into what a stack is, how functions get called and what values are pushed onto the stack, how return values get propagated to the caller and how parameters are being passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to know that a statement needs to finish and return and that you call `divide` or `combine` from `divide` works the same. Both need to finish before the next line of code can be executed or, if there are no more lines, the function returns. Yes, it's done with stack but it's really not important.

1. The state of the waiters variables `low`, `high` and `middle` is only the current invocations bindings so they don't get mixed with other invocations.
2. Every time you nest a new call it gets it's own variables and each need to finish. When the low-middle is finished it calls middle+1-high and when that finished combine. Those calls will do the same so you will have deeper nesting and how the call structure will be visited is like like a binary tree structure with the leafs being `low == high` (one element).

A word of advice. When looking at recursive code try doing it from leaf to more complex tree. eg. try it out with base case first, then the simplest of default case. eg.

1. 1 element array: does nothing
2. 2 element array: -> 1 element array (see 1.), 1 element array, combine
3. 4 element array: -> 2 element array (see 2.), 2 element array, combine

Notice that the 2. you know both recursive calls won't do anything and `combine` will do perhaps a swap. The 3. does 2. twice (including the swap) before `combine` that will merge 2 2 element arrays that are sorted. You are perhaps looking at it the other way, which requires you to halt 3. to do 2. that halts it and does 1., then the next 1, then back to 2. to do the text that has two 1s... It needs pen and paper. Looking at it from leaf to root using what you have learned of it so far lets you understand it much easier. I do think functional recursion is easier to grasp than mutating structures like your merge sort. eg. fibonacci sequence.